# mysql result to array

Tags: php

how is the fastest way to make a mysql result to an array?

```
static function result($sql){
    if(!$result = self::$link->query($sql)){
        echo 'SQL: '.$sql.'<br>'.self::$link->error;
    }

    return $result;
}

static function rows($sql, $mode='assoc'){
    $result = self::result($sql);

    $row_arr = array();
    if($mode == 'assoc'){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) $row_arr[] = $row;
    }
    elseif($mode == 'row'){
        while($row = $result->fetch_row()) $row_arr[] = $row;
    }
    $result->close();

    return $row_arr;
}
```

Comment: Faster than what you have? How fast is it? Is it slow? Have you done any profiling?

Comment: isn't there a method in mysqli which can do it?

Comment: Don't know, have you had a look at the documentation? It seems there is  (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) if you have the native driver.

Comment: downvoted as this seems to be a RTFM question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mysqli_result::fetch_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

Comment: what does it mean that its available only with mysqlnd?

Comment: "As mysqli_fetch_all() returns all the rows as an array in a single step, it may consume more memory than some similar functions such as mysqli_fetch_array(), which only returns one row at a time from the result set. Further, if you need to iterate over the result set, you will need a looping construct that will further impact performance. For these reasons mysqli_fetch_all() should only be used in those situations where the fetched result set will be sent to another layer for processing."

Answer (score 0):

MySQLND means native driver.

> The PHP script language features three different "extensions" to connect to the MySQL Server. The PHP term "extension" is comparable to the MySQL terms "Connector" and "Driver", please check the MySQL Reference Manual for details. The following extensions exist:
>
> - ext/mysql
> - ext/mysqli
> - PDO_MYSQL
>
> All PHP MySQL extensions are part of the source code of PHP. The source code and binaries are available from http://php.net. Both the PHP manual and the MySQL Reference Manual contain a detailed documentation of which extension to use.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/

Comment: This should be a comment to my answer. Please delete it and add the comment to my answer or I'll flag this in 5 minutes.

Comment: I'm unable to comment though.

Answer (score -1):

```
function returnMeArray(){
    $q = mysql_query("your query");
    $myarray = array();
    while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
        $myarray = $arr;
    }
    return $myarray;
}
```

Comment: `$myarray = $arr` should be `$myarray[] = $arr` else the $myarray will be overridden and I guess this does the same as what clarkk showed in his example

Comment: Don't think so. It is wrong, have you tested it? It'll return just the latter row...